# How DataTables determine columns type

Tags: datatables

I have a dynamic table enhanced by jQuery DataTables, which display a custom object similar to this [example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html).

**JSON:**

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": {
        "display": "SomeString",
        "timestamp": 1303686000
      },
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    // ... skipped ...
]}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: "data/orthogonal.txt",
        columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "extn" },
            { data: {
                _:    "start_date.display",
                sort: "start_date.timestamp"
            } },
            { data: "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

The difference is that I dynamically build the columns configuration, because the columns can be in any order, and others columns can be added or removed from the list. For this example (my case is very similar) the problem is that for some reason the `timestamp` property is ordered as a String instead of being ordered as a number.

I discovered that after setting the column "type" as "number" the ordering works perfectly. I'm presuming that DataTables is auto detecting the column as "String" for some reason (maybe because the display element is a string).

How does DataTables set the type of the columns, when is not explicitly declared?

**Edit 1**

I made a sample code to show the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/Teles/agrLjd2n/16/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery DataTables has built-in mechanism for type detection. There are multiple predefined functions for [various types](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) with fallback to `string` data type.

It's also possible to use [third-party plug-ins](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection/) or write your own.

There are multiple ways to specify data type, below are just the few.

> **SOLUTION 1**

Use [`type`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: "data/orthogonal.txt",
        columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "extn" },
            { data: "start_date.display", type: "date" },
            { data: "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

> **SOLUTION 2**

Use returned JSON data for type detection, see [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#object) for more information.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: "data/orthogonal.txt",
        columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "extn" },
            { data: {
                _:    "start_date.display",
                sort: "start_date.timestamp",
                type: "start_date.timestamp",
            } },
            { data: "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw the columns type earlier, but I want to change how DataTables mechanism for type detection. I look the plugins code and understood that they all check the "display" value of the cell to detect the type. I want to check the "sort" value of the cell, is that possible?

Comment: @RafaelTeles, setting the column [`type`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) and/or using a plug-in is the best approach. Alternatively you can define a [`render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option and provide a custom value for type detection mechanism (argument `type` is equal to `'type'` when DataTables performs type detection).

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer =/. I'm using renders to define the "sort", "filter" and "_ (default)" property of the columns, I could also set the type of the column, but I would prefer to use a plugin as you suggested.I debbuged a plugin code, and saw that the plugin detects the type by looking at the display value of the cells of the first row, I want to that with the "sort" value of the cells

Comment: @RafaelTeles, why would you need to do that? I fail to see why you should need to go around the rendered `sort` value for that. You must have a really special case, but you only mention timestamps? Perhaps I just dont understand, but as by many questions on SO and IRL / personally experience people sometimes crossing the river to get water.

Comment: For instance, I have a column with the calue [[d : 180 (3%), s : 109], [d : 90 (1.5%), s : 90], [d : 45 (0.75%), s : 45], where "d" is the display of the cell and "s" the sort. For some reason the dataTables is ordering those cell (of the same column) as String, so instead of having [109(3%), 90(1.5%), 45(0.75%)] i'm getting [90(1.5%), 45(0.75%), 109(3%)]

Comment: @RafaelTeles, you have an answer in your question to use `type: 'num'`, and your fiddle demonstrates that it works. Not sure what is the question anymore.

Comment: Datatables auto detect the type of the "display" property of the column, I want to use the "sort" property to detect the type. As far as I understand, the type of the column only impacted in the sorting process, if that is true, I would prefer to detect the type of the column checking the "sort" value. I don't want to specify the type on "every" column

Comment: In my fiddle code I want the "values" of each cell to be compared as number not as text without expliciting configuring the column type.

Comment: @RafaelTeles, You can add `type` property in your data along with `_`, and `sort` to indicate value for type detection, see [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#object). However that will increase the data size. All you need to do is specify the `type` in columns definition which is what it is developed for. You can use [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to specify [`type`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) for multiple columns once. I think you're trying to solve non-existing problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are walking in circles here =/. I know that I can set the type of the column, I just don't want to set it if it's not necessary... if I specify the "sort" value of the columns cells I just want datatables to auto detect the type checking the sort value not the "display" value. If dataTables did that, I wouldn't have to specify the type. It's not a problem to specify the type, but I just want to make it easier for me, if I can't detect the type checking the "sort" value type, I'll have to set the column type for all the system tables

Comment: You've got to understand that my table is not static (as I said in the question) the user can fully customize the table, changing column order and displayed columns. I can set the type of the column, but I want to dataTables auto detect the type checking the "sort" value instead of checking the "display" value

Comment: @RafaelTeles, You misunderstood me, there is `type` property that could be specified in the **JSON** data similar to `_` and `sort`, see [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#object). This is different from `type` initialization option.

Comment: Thanks! I finally understood, I was blindly ignoring the "type" property of data, now all makes sense, I thought that DataTables always tried to detect the type checking the "display" value where actually it checks the "type" property, since I wasn't specifying the "type" it was checking the "_ (default)" which was the same value of the "display"

Answer (score 3):

DataTables always check the "type" property of the column "data" to auto detect the type of the column, if no "type" property is specified it will check the default value "_".

So if you want DataTables to auto detect the type of the column checking the type of your "sort" property you should set the "type" property of data to be equals to your "sort" value

Here is a sample [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Teles/agrLjd2n/19/) with different approchs to achieve what I was tryng to do. Thanks @Gyrocode.com and @davidkonrad.

```
var Cell = function(display, value) {
    this.display = display;
    this.value = value;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var cells = [
        new Cell("120 (10%)", 120),
        new Cell("60 (5%)", 60),
        new Cell("30 (2.5%)", 30)
    ];

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: cells,
        columns: [
            { 
                title : "Column NOT OK",
                data: {
                    _:    "display",
                    sort: "value"
                } 
            }, { 
                type : "num",
                title : "Column Ok setting column type",
                data: {
                    _:    "display",
                    sort: "value"
                } 
            }, { 
                title : "Column Ok changing default value",
                data: {
                    _:    "value",
                    display: "display",
                    filter: "display"
                } 
            }, { 
                title : "Column Ok setting data type",
                data: {
                    _:    "display",
                    sort: "value",
                    type: "value"
                }  
            }, { 
                type : "num",
                title : "Column Not OK",
                data: "display"
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```