# Datatables 1.10: type = 'type' in render function

Tags: jquery, datatables

According to [the docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Types), when the columns.render parameter is a function, it has four arguments, one of them being 'type':

> The type call data requested - this will be 'filter', 'display',
> 'type' or 'sort'.

I understand each option, except for type being 'type'. I couldn't find any information about when or why the type argument would be 'type'.

Does anyone know when or why type = 'type'? what's its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data, type="type" is "type detection data" - the data used to auto-detect the [column type](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type).

> ```
> /*{
>     "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
>     "position":   "System Architect",
>     "start_date": "1303682400",
>     "office":     "Edinburgh"
> }*/
>
> {
>     data: 'start_date',
>     render: function ( data, type, row ) {
>         // If display or filter data is requested, format the date
>         if ( type === 'display' || type === 'filter' ) {
>             var d = new Date( data * 1000 );
>             return d.getDate() +'-'+ (d.getMonth()+1) +'-'+ d.getFullYear();
>         }
>
>         // Otherwise the data type requested (`type`) is type detection or
>         // sorting data, for which we want to use the integer, so just return
>         // that, unaltered
>         return data;
>     }
> }
> ```

I don't think it's often useful to provide different data when type="type".

Comment: Thank you! It finally clicked! your answer, along with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32286694/5796253) (which I found thanks to your answer) were really helpful.

and yeah, we might be suffering a case of [Semantic Satiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation) with the word 'type' ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be it's a mistake / typo in the documentation.  The paragraph above defines three types:

> function render( data, type, row, meta )
>
> Description:
>
> If a function is given, it will be executed whenever DataTables needs
>   to get the data for a cell in the column. Note that this function
>   might be called multiple times, as DataTables will call it for the
>   different data types that it needs - *sorting, filtering and display*.

Comment: That's what I thought, but including a console.log(type) inside a render function shows  that 'type' actually gets passed to the function. Weird...

Comment: Interesting.  I would put a post on the Datatables forum and ask the developer(s) directly.  They are usually pretty good about responding.